# KeyEvent getActionCommand for f9 key?

Tags: java, swing, awt, key-bindings, actionevent

My code for handling some keypresses was working fine when the keyboard keys were all normal (a-z), but now I want to make the default screenshot key be <kbd>F9</kbd>.

```
if (e.getActionCommand().toUpperCase().equals(configFile.getProperty("TOGGLE_ATTACK_KEY"))){
    inAttackMode = !inAttackMode;
} else if (e.getActionCommand().toUpperCase().equals(configFile.getProperty("SCREENSHOT_KEY"))){
```

e.getActionCommand() is returning null when I press the <kbd>F9</kbd> key.  The code to register this key is here:

```
theDesktop.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released " + configFile.getProperty("SCREENSHOT_KEY")), "f9ButtonRelease");
theDesktop.getActionMap().put("f9ButtonRelease", ClassKeyReleaseHandler);
```

Thanks for any help on this... I tried to search Google and SO but did not see anything specific.  Also tried using VK_F9 to register, but it only fires with <kbd>F9</kbd>(either way it returns null when I press <kbd>F9</kbd>).  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the reasons for using Key Bindings is to avoid the use of nested if/else statements. Instead you create a unique Action for the key binding, then the action command is irrelevant.

```
//theDesktop.getActionMap().put("f9ButtonRelease", ClassKeyReleaseHandler);
theDesktop.getActionMap().put("f9ButtonRelease", ScreenShotReleaseHandler);
```

This is the way all the default Actions are created in Swing.

Comment: so that is what I have and then there are a ton of inner classes for each functionality... ClassSendButton(Enter), ClassTabKey(Tab), ClassExitButton(Logout).  Is this okay?  If so I will keep them seperate and get rid of the ifs.

Comment: Using inner classes (that is how most of the Swing components work, take a look at the DefaultEditorKit source code for example) or a separate class is fine.

Comment: Okay thanks.  I just didn't want to have so many inner classes.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: not relevant for OP's question.

If you want to use the constant KeyEvent.VK_F9. You should not be using e.getActionCommand, but e.getKeyCode.

for example:

```
    public class TestListener implements KeyListener{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F9)
            System.out.println("F9 is pressed");

    }
```

Comment: The OP is, correctly, using the key bindings API not a KeyListener

Comment: Yes I posted on here a long time ago and someone pointed me to key bindings... I just was unsure of seperating every functionality into an inner class... hopefully Camickr or you, MadProgrammer, can ease my mind and let me know if that is good programming standard.

Comment: I bow down to the wise, i am still a greenhorn. And Shall from now on deduct wether or not i am capable to answer:) hope you find your answer, OP!

Comment: No worries at all.. you are doing the right thing(helping others) thats what counts